# insert string after matching ansible python regex

Tags: python, ansible

working on an ansible task at work.

Trying to configure pam.d/system-auth file using ansible module lineinfile the documentation explains I can use python regex.

I want to use patterns like "auth   required   pam_env.so" and insert the line I need at the end this is what I have so far.

```
 - name: CIS Ensure password requirements
    lineinfile:
      path: /var/tmp/system-auth
      backrefs: yes
      regexp: ^((auth).+)((require).+)(pam_env.so)*$
      line: '\1 123'
```

I expect to get:

```
auth   required     pam_env.so 123
```

But I get this:

```
auth    123
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your regular expression and backreference usage is not quite correct. Here is one way to match and insert the line properly:

```
- name: CIS Ensure password requirements
  lineinfile:
    path: /var/tmp/system-auth
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '^(auth\s+required\s+pam_env\.so.*)$' 
    line: '\1 123'
```

- The regexp '^(auth\s+required\s+pam_env.so.*)$' will match the entire line starting with 'auth' and capture it in backreference \1.
- \s+ matches 1 or more whitespace characters.
- .* at the end matches any characters after pam_env.so
- The $ anchors the match to the end of the line.
- The line '\1 123' inserts the captured line \1 followed by 123.

So this will find the line starting with auth, capture the whole line, and append 123 to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it! The '?' quantifier with '*' quantifier for the other two patterns seems to get my desired result like this:

```
- name: CIS Ensure password requirements
    lineinfile:
      path: /var/tmp/system-auth
      backrefs: yes
      regexp: ^((auth).*)((required)*?)((pam_env.so)*?).*$
      line: '\1 123'
```

Gives me this:

```
auth    required     pam_env.so 123
```

~